# It it possible to make windows 7 not detect/spin up my secondary hard drive after resuming from sleep?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

I only use it once a month for backup and don't want it spinning up/becoming active needlessly. I use Hotswap! to spin it down and making it disappear from my computer/device manager so it can't be written to. However after coming back from sleep windows automatically detects the drive, installs drivers for it etc.

- Tried disabling Upnp host and SSDP discovery service
- My BIOS does not have an option to disable HDDs.

Also if it's possible to get the same effect after restart that'd be great.

Comment: Most unlikely. Windows as an OS automatically loads and mounts all drives it comes across.

Answer (score 0):

Try Device Manager.
Goto to Disk
Right click on the disk you want and select Disable
The hard drive should no longer appear or be useable.

You will have to check if the hard drive goes into power save or not.
If you physically feel the drive there you should be able to tell if it is on or not.

Comment: This only works until computer is restarted/resumes from sleep. Anyway I'm just going to physically disconnect/connect the power cable once every month, bought an extension SATA-cable and will have it outside of chassi through one of the addon-card openings.